# Storing a collection of unique functions

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Storing a collection of unique functions</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assert.css">
  <script src="assert.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var store = {
    nextId: 1,
    cache: {},
    add: function(fn) {
      if (!fn.id) {
        fn.id = this.nextId++;
        this.cache[fn.id] = fn;
        return true;
      }
    }
  };

  function ninja() {}

  assert(store.add(ninja), "Function was safely added.");
  assert(!store.add(ninja), "But it was only added once.");

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**this is the assert.js file**

```js
function assert(value, text) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = value ? "pass" : "fail";
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  var results = document.getElementById("results");
  if (!results) {
    results = document.createElement("ul");
    results.setAttribute('id','results');
    document.body.appendChild(results);
  }
  results.appendChild(li);
}

function pass(text) { assert(true, text); }
function fail(text) { assert(false, text); }
function report(text) { pass(text); }
```

this code is from 'secrets of javascript ninja, second edition'. My question is about `if (!fn.id)` this line of code. what is id? what about the ! logical not before the fn?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805800/storing-a-collection-of-unique-functions/51805842#51805842 "If you see this tell me to upvote your question") @monirehd for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The name `fn` is an alias for any argument (`Ninja` function) you pass to the method `store.add`. The property `fn.id` offers a unique way to identify a `Ninja` function inside `store.cache`.

The check `if (!fn.id)` is used to check whether the `id` is falsey, which in this case means the property hasn't been defined. If it's not defined, you define it by setting it to `store.nextID` and then you use that id as a key to store and access `fn` inside `store.cache`.

Answer (score 0):

since everything in javascript is an object, even a function is an object. the coder tries to check if that function has an id, by using this statement `!fn.id` check the snippet bellow

```js
function sayHi() {
  console.log("Hola")
}

sayHi() // "Hola"

//lets check if the function has an id
//(it can be any variable we want, not only id)
console.log(sayHi.id) // undefined

//since javascript returns true in an (!undefined) statement
console.log(!undefined) // true

//we can use this to check if variables are undefined (or unset)

if(!sayHi.id) {
  console.log("sayHi.id is not defined: "+sayHi.id)
} else {
  console.log("sayHi.id is defined: "+sayHi.id)
}

//we can go ahead and declare it

sayHi.id = 21

if(!sayHi.id) {
  console.log("sayHi.id is not defined: "+sayHi.id)
} else {
  console.log("sayHi.id is defined: "+sayHi.id)
}

// so by saying (!fn.id), the coder is just trying to check if the function doesnt have an id already
```